# Why do multiple time-based triggers on scheduled task not work as expected?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, task-scheduler

I have a problem with a task in Windows Task Scheduler on Windows Server 2008 R2 (German):

A task has multiple (here: two) time based triggers. The first trigger is of the weekly type (a fixed time every friday), the second trigger is a once-only trigger with a date on the wednesday before the next friday.

[image: Picture showing the aforementioned task with its triggers and the next execution date. Although the picture shows the German interface, it should be self-explaining.]
**Why is the next execution time on the next friday, even though the second trigger specifies the wednesday before that?**

I tried searching for reference material, but [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383619%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [Technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc748841.aspx) didn't provide any useful information and I didn't find an answer here, too.

Did I miss anything? Is it behaving as intended and are my expectations wrong? How do I trigger a task for an off-the-regular-schedule-execution, then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a known bug.

Ref: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/950035 / http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2495489

If it bothers you too much, apply the noted hotfix.

*P.S. You should search for bugs in english from time to time ;)*

Comment: Thanks so far, I suppose this will be the solution. - And I do conduct searches in English, even almost exclusively so. My search terms were probably a little bit too specific. I didn't find any of your results when I looked this up! - I didn't really expect it to be a display error, though. Maybe I was too fixed on my slightly off direction. - I will accept your answer once I have it verified as correct.

Comment: Quite strange! Maybe you got bitten by google's personalized search results crap. Can be a real PITA. / I did go for a display error straightaway, because it contradicts itself glaringly. But yes, I could be wrong still.

Comment: You were not, I tested it with two triggers in short succession earlier and it worked splendidly: Both triggered, although only the run time for the second in order (first in list) was displayed. Now the hotfix is scheduled for testing and eventual deployment.

Comment: I had the same strange display and it's good to know it's just a display issue and the second trigger will still fire.