# Defining multiple triggers for my Task Scheduler will only work on the first trigger

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, scheduled-task, task-scheduler

I have "Windows server 2008 R2 standard" with SP1. and inside my windows Task Scheduler, i define the following 2 triggers:-

[image]

now as the picture is mentioning, i want to run the task on different times (3:00 am & 4:30 am) based on the Day. but currently only the first trigger is active . Today is Wednesday @15:00, but the next run for the task is showing that it will be Friday @3:00 instead of Thursday @4:30. so Thursday (which is define inside the second trigger) was skipped.

so can anyone advise on this?

Comment: There is really not enough information in your question. For an actual answer, I recommend you dump the task config info in xml format and post here. Also, what's with blotting out the year? Is that somehow secret? ;)

Comment: @ExtraT can you let me know what info i need to add to my question ? as you can see i have 2 triggers to run a task, now the next run should be on Thursday 4:30 (since Now is Wednesday 15:00).. but the task scheduler has skipped the second trigger and it is showing that the next run will be on Friday 3:00 instead of Thursday 4:30...i i have showed the year inside the picture..

Comment: Check this out: https://ss64.com/nt/schtasks.html
Windows tasks are ridiculously overbloated with features and they can be confusing sometimes. This is why it's important to dump the full task definition in XML to properly troubleshoot this crap.

Comment: @ExtraT yes i agree with you.. now i find it easier to create 2 separate tasks for the time being ,, till i find a fix...

Comment: Take a look at this answer: https://serverfault.com/a/542959/450038. It might just be displaying wrong, but triggering correctly.